# Calculate word frequency in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, term-document-matrix

I am trying to create a dataframe where the first column ("Value") has a multi-word string in each row and all other columns have labels representing unique words from all strings in "Value". I want to populate this dataframe with the word frequency for every string (a row) checking against all unique words (columns). In a sense, create a simple TDM

```
rows = ['you want peace', 'we went home', 'our home is nice', 'we want peace at home']
col_list = [word.lower().split(" ") for word in rows]
set_col = set(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(col_list)))

columns = set_col
ncols = len(set_col)

testDF = pd.DataFrame(columns = set_col)
testDF.insert(0, "Value", " ")

testDF["Value"] = rows
testDF.fillna(0, inplace=True)

irow = 0

for tweet in testDF["Value"]:

    for word in tweet.split(" "):
        for col in xrange(1, ncols):

            if word == testDF.columns[col]: testDF[irow, col] += 1

    irow += 1

testDF.head()
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-9a991295ccd9> in <module>()
     23         for col in xrange(1, ncols):
     24 
---> 25             if word == testDF.columns[col]: testDF[irow, col] += 1
     26 
     27     irow += 1

C:\Users\Tony\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   1795             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   1796         else:
-> 1797             return self._getitem_column(key)
   1798 
   1799     def _getitem_column(self, key):

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3824)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3704)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   (pandas\hashtable.c:12280)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12231)()

KeyError: (0, 9)
```

I am not sure what is wrong thus, will appreciate your help
Also, if there is a cleaner way to do this (except NO textmining - problem with installing) it would be great to learn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what your complete program is trying to do , but if by the following -

```
testDF[irow, col]
```

You mean't to index the cell in the dataframe, with `irow` as the index and `col` as the column, you cannot use simple subscript for that. You should insteand use `.iloc` or such. Example -

```
 if word == testDF.columns[col]: testDF.iloc[irow, col] += 1
```

Use `.iloc` if you intended for `irow` to the the 0-indexed number of the index , if `irow` is the exact index of the DataFrame, you can use `.loc` instead of `.iloc` .

Comment: .iloc works like a breeze! Still new to Python and keep forgetting  that access to dataframe elements is different from that for pd.arrays:)